# how to to do "ab not dc" regex search in mongodb

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

i need to do regex bases search on a single field which has a condtion "ab not dc". below query results error. suggest a proper query to use

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate(
[
{$match:{search_description:{$regex: "ab", "$options": "i"}}}
,{$match:{search_description:{$not:{$regex: "dc", "$options": "i"}}}}
]
)
```

above query results **"errmsg" : "bad query: BadValue $not cannot have a regex"** error message

Comment: Use the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word to develop a single regular expression to include the negation

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Comment: it worked out for me with some minor changes based on my requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since MongoDB supports negative lookahead, you can use

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate(
    [
        {$match:{search_description:{$regex: "^(?!.*db).*ab.*$", "$options": "i"}}}
    ]
)
```